# f:selectItem itemEscaped=false not unescaping HTML in p:selectOneButton labels

Tags: jsf, primefaces, icons, html-escape, selectonebutton

I'm working with PrimeFaces 5.3. I have the next f:selectItem in a p:selectOneButton

```
 <f:selectItem itemEscaped="false" itemLabel="&lt;i class=&quot;fa fa-fort-awesome&quot;&gt;&lt;/i&gt;" itemValue="0" />
```

It shows directly this html code:

```
<i class="fa fa-fort-awesome"></i>
```

instead shows the font awesome icon.

Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: what **should** it show? Looks like it is showing the right thing... Oh and **always** post PF version!

Comment: It should show a font awesome icon. Anyway, any HTML code is displaying incorrectly. Works with <h:outputText escape="false" value="&lt;i class=&quot;fa fa-fort-awesome&quot;&gt;&lt;/i&gt;" /> but I want in a f:selectItem

Comment: But you stated : "instead shows the font awesome icon." So you mean it does **not** show the icon... and but 'plain' text of the 'html'?

Comment: yes, sorry for my english, I only show 'plain' text of the 'html'

Comment: Did you also try `itemLabelEscaped='false'`?

Comment: I thing it's a PF bug...

Comment: Yes it might be. You can check the source for this